# delete animation on :leave in angular animations

Tags: angular

I

```
<div *ngIf="!destroy">
        <menu
            *ngIf="visible$ | async"
            [@MenuTransitions]
            [@.disabled]="animationDisabled"
        >
        <menu>
</div>
```

Now i'm settings destroy to true on ngOnDestroy and what is happening - the animation in menu on :leave does work, how to just make it doesnt work?